# Run Script for Kafka in local machine

Tags: apache-kafka

My project needs to kafka process. therefore, I downloded kafka_2.11-2.0.0 in my local machine. As you know, there are a lot of scripts for make this in bin directory, such as:

- kafka-run-class.sh
- kafka-topics.sh
- kafka-server-start.sh

Which scripts are required to standing up Kafka ?

Comment: `kafka-server-start` calls `kafka-run-class`, but Zookeeper is also required to start Kafka, as shown on the Quickstart page of the Kafka site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unzip the tar.

Then issue these commands from inside the unzipped folder (you need to start zookeeper server first, then start kafka server):

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties 

bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

This will start Apache Kafka with default configurations.